# onchange text of textbox display on another textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I want to display changing text into another text box

I tried [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CSFkm/1/) for evey possible combination. But didn't work.

```
/*$('input#list_val').keyup(function() {
   //perform ajax call...
  // alert("Hello");
   $('#list_v').text($(this).val());
});*/
$('input#list_val').keydown(function() {
   //perform ajax call...
   //alert("Hello");
   $('#list_v').text($(this).val());
});


<input type='text' id="list_val" />
<input type='text' id="list_v" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `val()` for adding value to input and use keyup rather than keydown to show value in other input immediately

```
$('input#list_val').keyup(function() {
   $('#list_v').val($(this).val());
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSFkm/4/)

Answer (score 1):

use .val() and .keyup (using keydown doesn't register the newest value, it registers the value before so keyup is better to use for this)

```
$('#list_val').keyup(function() {
   $('#list_v').val(this.value);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/CSFkm/6/)

Answer (score 0):

change from :

```
$('#list_v').text($(this).val());
```

to:

```
$('#list_v').val($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $list_v = $('#list_v');
$('input#list_val').keyup(function() {
   $list_v.val($(this).val());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LzakF/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**js**

```
$('#list_val').keyup(function() {
   $('#list_v').val($('#list_val').val());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CSFkm/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input#list_val').keydown(function() {
    var text = $("input#list_val").val();
    $('#list_v').html(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect, Just need to change small things in your code :

```
$('#list_val').keydown(function() {  
   $('#list_v').val($(this).val());
});
```